# Determine and sketch the image of function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

I have to sketch the image of function $h\left(\mathbb R^{2} \right)$ as **1. a set** and as **2. a geometric object**.

$h\left(r,\phi\right)=\begin{pmatrix} rcos\phi \\ rsin\phi \\ r \end{pmatrix} $

I really dont know how to even start, and didnt find any help on google. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The trick is to vary $\phi$ and $r$ separately. Note for example that for any fixed $r$ varying $\phi$ gives you a circle of radius $r$ around the $z$ axis at height $r$.

Comment: Do you recognize the first two entries of $h$ as polar coordinates? If you hold $r$ fixed in the $z$ coordinate, the $x,y$ coordinates describe a circle of radius $r$ at height $r$. (3D Graph: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQXD4.png)

Comment: But how to do it as a set?

Comment: $h(\mathbb{R}^2) = \left\lbrace (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2=r^2 \text{ and }z=r  \right\rbrace$ maybe? (circle of radius $r$ in the $x/y$ plane, $z$ coordinate must be $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Correction and summary of the comments.

The first two components of $h(r,\phi)$ are polar coordinates, wich represent a circle of radius $r$ (if $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$ or $\phi$ runs through all of $\mathbb{R}$). That is, usual polar coordinates are:

$$\Phi(r,\varphi) = \begin{pmatrix}r\cos \varphi \\ r\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}$$

The $z$-component of $h$ is $r$, meaning that if we put it all together, we have a circle of radius $r$ in the $xy$-Plane at the height ($z$-coordinate) $r$. This means that starting from $z=0$, we make a circle of radius $0$ in the $xy$ plane, then as we move the $z$ coordinate upwards, we start drawing bigger and bigger circles. The graph represents that pretty nicely:

[image]

If we want to represent this as a set, we can use the formula for a circle in cartesian (x,y) coordinates, which is $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$ for a circle of radius $r$ in the $x,y$ plane. However, we also require $r$ to be the $z$-component, so all in all we have

$$h(\mathbb{R}^2) = \left\lbrace (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2=r^2 \text{ and }z=r \right\rbrace $$
That expression still has $r$ in it, however. But since $r=z$ we can also write

$$h(\mathbb{R}^2) = \left\lbrace (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2=z^2  \right\rbrace $$
Which is now the correct answer. Asking Wolfram Alpha on what that equation means, it gives us our cones again.

[image: c2]